# Why both IF and ELSE case been excuted?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
private static synchronized String[][] map2data(Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (map != null) {
        String[][] msg_data = (String[][]) map.get("message_data");
        return msg_data;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My java code of my android project is as below. When I debug it in eclipse, after `String[][] msg_data = (String[][]) map.get("message_data");` executed, it goes to `return null;`  in the `else` case.

I'm totally confused about this. Firstly I guess there's something wrong in the `String[][] msg_data = (String[][]) map.get("message_data");`, but when I change it to`String a = "a"`, it is still the same. Why?
May it because "static synchronized "or something else?

Comment: Why `map.get("message_data")` can't be `null`?

Comment: How do you know that both are getting executed? Please check that "message_data" is not null and get its class.

Comment: You can set breakpoint at ''return null''

Comment: i prefer taking the default returns out of `else`

Comment: thank you,but I am not just watch the return value but using F6 to watch how it executed,it clearly execute the "return null;" in the else case,that's confuse me most.

Comment: Make sure your eclipse code is in sync with code deployed in server. Redeploy.

Comment: @shenhengbin I have set a breakpoint on the "return null;" and its executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from your code it never be happen..

Check your `msg_data` in `if statement` may be its **null**. And if you debug it correctly may be your code be out of sync. So build once again..

**EDIT:**

Remove else part from it, use this code,

**CODE:**

```
private static synchronized String[][] map2data(Map<String, Object> map) {
String[][] msg_data = null;
    if (map != null) {
        msg_data = (String[][]) map.get("message_data");
       } 
return msg_data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its the way it shows.. you may also notice that in that else statement only `return` statement is highlighted while debugging and not the statements before it... it never really executes.. Try printing something in that `else` condition using Log

Comment: This was the case for me. My `return` from my `else` was hitting the breakpoint even when the `if` hit, but it wasn't actually hitting it as verified with a log statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have your code and binaries out-of-sync. Try to recompile and you should not see it anymore.

Comment: thank you,but I cleaned my project and rebuild it seavral times and it still the same...